# Can't use RStudio any more after trying to set up an ODBC connection to a postgreSQL database

Tags: software-installation, postgresql, debugging, r

I tried to Setup an odbc connection from R to my PostgreSQL database located on a server (package RODBC). When trying to connect the connection failed because I entered a wrong Username in the DSN connection defined in odbc.ini.

So I changed `odbc.ini` and tried again but then RStudio froze. So I killed the process and tried to start the application again. Unfortunately now RStudio didn't start at all anymore (the app in the launcher blinks but does not open the UI). I already uninstalled the application with

```
sudo apt-get purge rstudio
```

and reinstalled it again. I updated and upgraded all packages...but still the same error. Also trying to start the program from terminal typing rstudio does not give any result. So any idea how to debug this and get Rstudio working again?

Edit: when i start rstudio from terminal with

```
rstudio &
```

it shows me the ID 7547. Still this ID doesn't appear in the processes list in the system monitor.

Comment: ok I got it working again by entering "sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales". don't aks me why...I have no idea.

Comment: Please write up your comment as an answer so others may benefit from your experience.

Comment: I can't i have not enough reputation...

Comment: You only need a rep of 1 to answer a question here, 10 to answer protected questions like this one, you have 55. If you'd rather not take the time, let me know and I'll do it, but I'd rather you did so I can upvote it.

Comment: i know it's wired...i have no option here to respond the question only to add comments. i get a sign below saying that " protected by fossfreedom♦ Jan 14 at 12:42" etc. Therefore it would be great if you could paste it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal.

Enter the command:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

This appears to resolve this problem.

Source: Joschi comment above.